# Derivative with respect to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

How do we start with the matrix differentiation of this kind of equation?
$$
V = \big[ y_t - Cx_t \big]^T R^{-1} \big[y_t - Cx_t \big]
$$

here $x_t$ and $y_t$ are vectors and $C$ and $R$ are matrices. $R$ is a covariance matrix (symmetric).

How do we find the derivative of $V$ with respect of matrix $C$?

Comment: You could try expanding $V(C+\Delta)$ and looking for the terms that are linear in $\Delta$. Keep in mind that $DV(C)$ is a linear map from matrices to a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V(C) = (Cx-y)^T R^{-1} (Cx-y)$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
V(C+\Delta)  &=& (Cx+\Delta x-y)^T R^{-1} (Cx+\Delta x-y) \\
&=& (Cx-y)^T R^{-1} (Cx-y) + (\Delta x)^T R^{-1} (Cx-y) +(Cx-y)^T R^{-1} \Delta x +(\Delta x)^T R^{-1} \Delta x \\
&=& V(C) + 2 (Cx-y)^T R^{-1} \Delta x +(\Delta x)^T R^{-1} \Delta x
\end{eqnarray}
From which we have $DV(C)(\Delta) = 2 (Cx-y)^T R^{-1} \Delta x$.

You can express the derivative  as a trace, as in $DV(C)(\Delta) = 2\operatorname{tr}(x (Cx-y)^T R^{-1} \Delta)$.

Comment: I have a question about the $\Delta$. Shouldn't it disappear from the derivative? I think we have to do something like limit $\Delta$ tends to zero, $(V(C+\Delta) - V(C) / \Delta$, right?

Comment: And can you also suggest some pointers from where I can practice these kinds of derivatives?

Comment: Well, this is a point that confuses a lot of folks. The derivative (in this case) is a linear map from the original space (of matrices) to scalars. There is no easy way to represent such a mapping without a '$\Delta$' of some sort. With scalars (or mappings of the form $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$) you can represent the derivative as a scalar (or an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively), however, no common convenient notation exists to represent a linear map of the form $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You could 'stretch' the matrix out into a long vector and compute the corresponding representative of the derivative, but it is no more convenient that the above representation in my opinion. I don't have any references or pointers, sorry. I usually expand as above and look for linear terms.

Comment: I'm still confused about the $\Delta$. But, I have to find the value of C where the derivative is zero. How do you proceed from your equation into finding the value of C setting it to zero?

Comment: Look at the equation and figure out what values of $C$ will make the equation zero for all $\Delta$. If $x=0$ then it is always zero, otherwise it is zero iff $Cx=y$.

Comment: @copper.hat is everything ok with the last equation (with a trace)?

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache: Did you have a question? The trace is invariant to cyclic shifts as in $\operatorname{tr} ( A B C ) = \operatorname{tr} ( C A B ) $. Expressing the derivative as a trace  means you can write $DV(C)(\Delta) = \langle 2 (x (Cx-y)^T R^{-1})^T,\Delta \rangle $, where the inner product is that from the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the differential

$$dV = (-dCx_t)^TR^{-1}(y_t-Cx_t) + (y_t-Cx_t)^TR^{-1}(-dCx_t) = -2x_t^T(dC)^TR^{-1}(y_t-Cx_t),$$
where the second step follows from $R$ being symmetric. For any tangent matrix $dC$ this gives you the change in $V$. You can plug in the delta matrix $dC_{i,j} = \delta_m(i)\delta_n(j)$ if you need the individual component derivatives $\frac{\partial V}{\partial C_{m,n}}.$

Comment: What rule did you use to get the first expression? Is it kind of the product rule?